Why buttons on a LazyVGrid are not always pressed within a Scroll view in macOS
I created a LazyVGrid within a ScrollView (vertical & horizontal).
Although the layout works as I expect, when the user interacts with the window (eg: by changing its size) then button sometimes do not react to mouse clicks.
import SwiftUI

struct Cell: Identifiable {
  var id: UUID = UUID()
  var i: Int = 0
  
  init(i: Int) {
    self.i = i
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var columns: [GridItem] = [GridItem](repeating: GridItem(.fixed(40), spacing: 5), count: 60)
  var cells: [Cell] = []

  init() {
    cells.removeAll()
    for i in 0..<180 {
      cells.append(Cell(i:i))
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
      LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 5) {
        ForEach(cells) { cell in
          ButtonView(cell: cell)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
  var cell: Cell
  @State var popOver: Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      popOver.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("\(cell.i)")
    }
    .popover(isPresented: $popOver, content: {
      Text("Information line of button \(cell.i)").padding()
    })
  }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

This video
demonstrates the problem I am facing.
As you can see, the code creates a grid of buttons. Every time I click on a button a popover should appear. After running the app, the popovers sometimes don't appear and sometimes appear in a shifted position.
I am running on a mac mini with an wide monitor and Xcode: 15.3 & macOS: 14.2

You shouldn’t be recreating cells in each init. Every time you do that, they have different IDs, since you’re randomly assigning a UUID. A good start would be keeping the cells in State and only creating them once.

Thank you for the tip, although this does not solve my issue...

Can you update your question with that change made? That will meaningfully change the results, whether or not its the only thing required.

I think you are right. Keeping the cells in State will make the popover work. But my app, needs these cells to be created dynamically since the number of them depends on a user selection. I noticed also that if I shrink the window, in order to make both scroll indicators visible then I cannot scroll the view using these indicators

For all those who may interested:
I found that if I place the ScrollView inside a view container (ex: a VStack) with another view before, then everything works fine.
Bellow you I post the complete code, which works (at least in my system):
import SwiftUI

struct Cell: Identifiable {
  var id: UUID = UUID()
  var i: Int = 0
  
  init(i: Int) {
    self.i = i
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var columns: [GridItem] = [GridItem](repeating: GridItem(.fixed(40), spacing: 5), count: 60)
  var cells: [Cell] = []

  init() {
    for i in 0..<180 {
      cells.append(Cell(i:i))
    }
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("")
      ScrollView([.horizontal, .vertical]) {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 5) {
          ForEach(cells) { cell in
            ButtonView(cell: cell)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ButtonView: View {
  var cell: Cell
  @State var popOver: Bool = false
  
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      popOver.toggle()
    } label: {
      Text("\(cell.i)")
    }
    .popover(isPresented: $popOver, content: {
      Text("Information line of button \(cell.i)").padding()
    })
  }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

